# Flutter How to call Widget with parameters from another file

Tags: flutter, dart

I created a class that stores widget named CardWidget with parameters. I stored it in different file to use it multiple times.
CardWidget is a Widget that contains text data like title, description,date and account. I need it to create special boards in home page like it used to be in different forums.

.Widget file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CardWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const CardWidget({Key? key, pcolor, ptext, paccount, pdate, peoplein}) : super(key: key);

  Widget CardWid({pcolor, ptext, paccount, pdate, peoplein}) {
    return Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15, vertical: 5),

        // data was erased for economy
        child: Container());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CardWid();
  }
}
```

When i call it from another flutter class it returns an issue.

> type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'

.main file, where i call the widget and give parameters

```
class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          CardWidget(
              pcolor: Colors.orangeAccent,
              ptext: 'I need team for First Person Shooter',
              paccount: 'gamedev21',
              pdate: 'February 12, 2023, 21:00',
              peoplein: 2),
          CardWidget(
              pcolor: Colors.green[700],
              ptext: 'text',
              paccount: 'text',
              pdate: 'February 12, 2023, 18:00',
              peoplein: 4),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Can you please edit the question and add the definition of named parameters of the `CardWidget`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## You should type your parameters in the constructor and define them in the Widget itself, like so

### Your issue exists because the values you pass to the `CardWidgets`'s constructor are not actually being saved anywhere, so when `CardWid` method is called, the parameters (of type `dynamic`) are null.

```dart
// Copyright (c) 2019, the Dart project authors.  Please see the AUTHORS file
// for details. All rights reserved. Use of this source code is governed by a
// BSD-style license that can be found in the LICENSE file.

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold(body:CardWidget(
      pcolor: Colors.orangeAccent,
      ptext: 'I need team for First Person Shooter',
      paccount: 'gamedev21',
      pdate: 'February 12, 2023, 21:00',
      peoplein: 2,
    ),);
  }
}

class CardWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const CardWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.pcolor,
    required this.ptext,
    required this.paccount,
    required this.pdate,
    required this.peoplein,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Color pcolor;
  final String ptext;
  final String paccount;
  final String pdate;
  final int peoplein;

  Widget cardWidget() {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15, vertical: 5),
      color: pcolor,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Text("$ptext, $paccount, $pdate, $peoplein"),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return cardWidget();
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You should probably explain the code and I don't think this answers the question